# do i need to do IIS reset for my host server if i modify my asp.net mvc-4 web.config file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-8

most of the articles which i read mentioned that if i do any modification to my web application web.config , then i need to do an iis reset to force my web application to get the new update.
but in my case i have the following:-

1. asp.net mvc-4 web application, using .net 4.5
2. i hosted my mvc web application using iis-8 windows server 2012 R2.

now i did these modifications to the mvc web.config file:-

-I added a new entry as follow:-

```
 <add key="ApiURL" value="https://****" />
```

-I modify an existing entry from "Version 1" to "Version 2" :-

```
<add key="version" value="Version 2" />
```

now i am referencing these entries inside my mvc-4 web application as follow:-

```
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiURL"];
```

and i noted that my web application was able to see the web.config updates (updating app setting entry & adding new entry) , without doing any iis reset or application pool reset... so can anyone advice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, once you modify the web.config, IIS realizes that the application needs to reload, and will unload the app pool.  You'll lose any in process caching as well.  This is why you see the changes in the web.config when you save it.